# Current sensor output impedance information

Tags: current-measurement, impedance, datasheet

I am using ZXCT1084QE5TA high-side current sensor, upon inspecting datasheet I came across this very weird output impedance information, which I don't really understand.

[image]

There are two versions of this chip, fixed gain and variable gain. Why does the variable gain variant has this impedance and what does it mean? 1||5 GΩ/pF? I thought impedance is measured in ohm, like in fixed gain variant 125 kΩ.

Comment: For 82Q and 83Q the output impedance is 1 GΩ and 5 pF in parallel (just like in scope inputs e.g. 1 MΩ and 15 pF in parallel). But I don't know why it's like that in 82Q and 83Q. Could be related to bandwidth-versus-gain.

Answer (score 1):

No, impedances are complex in general (otherwise we'd just call them resistances), and the units left and right of the || are specified in the rightmost column.

The || is a shorthand for "this resistance is in parallel with a capacitance".